# How to skin a (single) Spark Component to look like an MX Components

Tags: apache-flex, skin, flex-spark

### Question

I want to use a Spark ComboBox with numerous MX Components but the Spark ComboBox does not look the same as the MX Components.  *Is there a skin I can use to Skin Spark components like MX components?*

---

### Example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
    <s:VGroup>
        <s:HGroup>
            <s:Label text="SPARK: "/>
            <s:ComboBox 
                dataProvider="{...}"
                labelField="label"
                />
        </s:HGroup>
        <s:HGroup>
            <s:Label text="MX: "/>
            <mx:ComboBox
                dataProvider="{...}"
                labelField="label"
                />
        </s:HGroup>
    </s:VGroup>
</s:Application>
```

#### Neither Open:

[image]

#### Spark Open:

[image]

#### MX Open:

[image]

*Ideally I would like to skin the Spark Component to look identical to the MX Component*.

Answer (score 0):

Read about [using themes](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=styles_12.html).
You need a **halo** theme. Halo.swc can be found at **${FLEX_SDK_FOLDER}/frameworks/themes/Halo**. So pass the following parameter to compiler: `-theme ${FLEX_SDK_FOLDER}/frameworks/themes/Halo/Halo.swc`

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I looked into using themes but themes have to be applied globally to the application.  I only want to apply the change to one ComboBox instance.